# How can I have multiple listeners of StreamProvider where the listeners added later receive the most recent data?

Tags: flutter, riverpod

I have a firebase snapshot StreamProvider

```
final poiChangesProvider = StreamProvider.autoDispose((ref) {
  return db.collection(POI.colPois)
           .withConverter<POI>(
             fromFirestore: (snapshot, _) => ...,
             toFirestore: (poi, _) => ...)
           .snapshots();
});
```

When I ref.watch/listen to it I get all the POIs and then a stream of changes, as expected.
But when I ref.watch it from multiple places, the first one to watch gets all the initial data, while all other watchers only receive the following updates.

How can I make a provider that caches and returns the last streamed data to new listeners?
The [riverpod docs](https://docs-v2.riverpod.dev/docs/providers/stream_provider) for StreamProvider state that `it caches the latest value emitted by the stream, ensuring that if a listener is added after an event is emitted, the listener will still have immediate access to the most up-to-date event.` But I have not been able to make this happen.

Comment: How can this be reproduced with a simple example?

Comment: How exactly do you consume this provider? Anyway, I guess this discussion may be useful for your case: https://github.com/rrousselGit/riverpod/issues/1433

Answer (score 1, accepted):

StreamProvider keeping track of the last value and offering it to new listeners is the default behavior – assuming your listener is `ref.watch`.

If you are talking about `ref.listen`, it has an optional `fireImmediately` parameter:

```dart
// Inside providers
ref.listen(
  provider,
  fireImmediately: true,
  (previous, next) => print('value $next'),
);

// Inside consumers
ref.listenManual(
  provider,
  fireImmediately: true,
  (previous, next) => print('value $next'),
);
```

Comment: That's what I came up with in the end. Are there any concerns about using fireImmediately? I see very few example using it and it's mainly with tests.

Comment: No that's totally fine. It's here for this